# Strange Logisim error; subcircuit does not work in main

Tags: logisim, subcircuit

I have created a subcircuit that decides if a 3-bit signed binary digit A is larger than a 3-bit signed binary digit B. It works correctly in its subcircuit file.

It does not, however, work when added to my main. I have even added it to main and isolated it from the rest of the main circuit, and fed it inputs identical to the test inputs I tried in the subcircuit. in order to confirm it's not an error in my main, but this also does not give the right output.

I am using Logisim; is this potentially a Logisim error? The first picture is the subcircuit, the second is the subcircuit implemented in the main in isolation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many errors like this can be explained by some bad connection. For example, in the first circuit there is some unclear mess of wires on the right side, where the wires are crossing through gates, and are connected to gates "vertically" or with zero clearance. On the second circuit there are some connections with a "bubble" and some without. Start with organizing the circuits in a clear and consistent way, and you will either solve or spot your issue.

Comment: Why is the subcircuit named differently within _main_?

Comment: @Seir the circuit going wrong is called A_greater_than_B. It implements A_bigger_than_B and A0_bigger_than_B0.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have cleaned it up and updated the photo. I guess my real question is how is it even possible that it gives different results in main?

Comment: Would you mind to show the internals of the subcircuits, please, for us to reproduce? And what version of Logisim are you using? I never watched that small "b" in the pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately I was not able to solve this error even after getting help from some people much more knowledgeable than me. I believe that logisim was acting up. Instead I re-built the circuit with an initial subcircuit that checks the most weighty position which is a sign. If the signs are euqal, it moves on to another subcircuit for comparing bits. Each subcircuit has three outputs, A>B, equal, and A<B. Depending on which outputs have a value, a series of AND and OR gates will determine if A>B such that the entire subcircuit only has that one output. Thank you for taking time to look this over!